# Python regex text from jira to markdown formatting

Tags: python, regex, replace

I want to convert bold text formatting from Jira to markdown, and I'm running into a problem with lists. my code:

```py
re.sub(r"\*([^{}]+)\*", r"**\1**", text)
```

I was trying to replace all `*` with `**`, but this caused problems with displaying lists, turning them from this:

- first item
- second item
- third item

into this:
** first item
** second item
** last item

Does anyone know how to solve this issue?

Comment: Try `r"\*([^{}*\r\n]+)\*"`

Comment: That helps, but still causes problems when trying to use bold text within list item

Comment: Could you please explain what the pattern should match? How can you describe the contexts where the match should occur?

Comment: the match should occur only in situation when user is trying to write bold text in single line like that: ```*bold text* ```

Comment: `re.sub(r'^[^\S\n]*\* |\*([^*\r\n]*)\*', lambda x: process_this(x.group(1)) if x.group(1) else x.group(), text, flags=re.M)`. Replace `process_this` with what you actually want to do with the captured text between asterisks (e.g. `f'**{x.group(1)}**'`)

Comment: Try: `re.sub(r"\*([^*{}\n]+)\*", r"**\1**", text)`

Comment: I think the first one works better, the only issue is when i'm truing to add bolt rtext inside list item like this ```* this is a list item *and bold text inside*```. What might be helpful is that list item must have space between asterisk and first letter, when bold text shouldn't have the space

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```py
import re
text = r'''Some text *here*:
* first item
* second item
* third item *some bold text*
and the end of text.'''
print(re.sub(
    r'^[^\S\n]*\* |\*([^*\r\n]*)\*',
    lambda x: f'**{x.group(1)}**' if x.group(1) else x.group(), 
    text, 
    flags=re.M)
)
```

See the [Python demo](https://ideone.com/DV6958).

**Details**:

- `^` - start of string
- `[^\S\n]*` - zero or more whitespace chars other than LF
- `\*` - a `*` char
- `|` - or
- `\*` - a `*` char
- `([^*\r\n]*)` - Capturing group 1: any zero or more chars other than `*`, CR and LF
- `\*` - a `*` char

The `lambda x: f'**{x.group(1)}**' if x.group(1) else x.group()` replacement means that the match is replaced with `**` + Group 1 + `**` if Group 1 matched, else, no replacement occurs, the whole match is returned as is.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you take advantage from list-items required to start on *new line* with beginning asterisk followed by space?

Pseudo code:

```py
for each line:
  if not line starts with asterisk:
    replace single asterisk with double asterisk
  else:
    replace text following the leading asterisk
```